# Port mapping is not working in AKS while creating a POD using Kubectl command

Tags: azure-aks

I'm new to `AKS`, and trying to create a `POD` and a `Load Balancer` service to expose the pod to the internet. I  have an image of `.Net5 API application`. I created a `POD` with `Port=8080`. `(kubectl run net5pod --image net5demoapi:latest --port=8080)`, but when I tried to access my application by connecting to the pod `(kubectl exec -it net5pod -- /bin/bash)` with curl command and found that my application is running in `port 5000` not in `port 8080`. same happens with `Load Balancer service` too, the custom port which we give at the time of creating `POD/LB Service` is not working. Could someone let me  know is there any config or steps I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a web app, try this one instead of execute a shell in your pod = `kubectl port-forward pods/net5pod 8080`. now you can access your application via http://localhost:8080

It could be also that the container image has a entrypoint which starts on port 5000. Easiest solution is to create a service for the pod via `kubectl expose` and specify `--port=8080` and `--target-port=5000`. More Complex solution is to overwrite the entrypoint.

Also explained here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service